# aplay analog for darwin?

Tags: mac-osx, audio

On linux I can play a sound file with the aplay program. I can also send audio data to /dev/dsp in some cases.

What is the Darwin analog of the aplay program? I need something that is purely a CLI-based solution.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [qtplay](http://code.google.com/p/qtplay/).

Edit: Oops, I forgot about the built-in afplay(1). The man page tells you less than the usage statement, though.

$ afplay -h

```
Usage:
afplay [option...] audio_file

Options: (may appear before or after arguments)
  {-v | --volume} VOLUME
    set the volume for playback of the file
  {-h | --help}
    print help
  { --leaks}
    run leaks analysis  {-t | --time} TIME
    play for TIME seconds
  {-r | --rate} RATE
    play at playback rate
  {-q | --rQuality} QUALITY
    set the quality used for rate-scaled playback (default is 0 - low quality, 1 - high quality)
  {-d | --debug}
    debug print output
```